# Shell function definition: why is there a space after the opening brace?

Tags: shell-script

You probably know of that [fork bomb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159491/why-did-this-command-make-my-system-lag-so-bad-i-had-to-reboot):

```
 :(){ :|:&};: #WARNING: harmful code
```

I wonder why it is necessary, for it to parse, to include a space after the opening curly brace.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> {}
>
> ```
>           { list; }
> ```
>
> Placing a list of commands between curly braces causes the list to be executed in the current shell context. No subshell is created. The
>   semicolon (or newline) following list is required.
>
> In addition to the creation of a subshell, there is a subtle
>   difference between these two constructs due to historical reasons. The
>   braces are reserved words, so they must be separated from the list by
>   blanks or other shell metacharacters. The parentheses are operators,
>   and are recognized as separate tokens by the shell even if they are
>   not separated from the list by whitespace.

// [source](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping)

Comment: I've quibbled with your answer in my own post on this page. It's a function not a command grouping.

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully A function body *is* a command grouping.

Answer (score 3):

I think @rush may be giving a correct if misleading answer here. The fork-bomb defines a [function](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions) called "`:`". The code in the curly braces is not executed until the function is called by the final "`:`". So the curly braces as *command grouping* and the curly braces as *function body* are syntactically the same but have different semantics.
From the same [document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions) as @rush cites:

> Note that for historical reasons, in the most common usage the curly braces that surround the body of the function must be separated from the body by blanks or newlines. This is because the braces are reserved words and are only recognized as such when they are separated from the command list by whitespace or another shell metacharacter. Also, when using the braces, the list must be terminated by a semicolon, a ‘&’, or a newline.

Comment: No, rush's answer is correct. The curly braces around a function body are the same syntactic element as when they're not delimited a function body. See the [shell grammar rules](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_10_02): a `function_body` is a `compound_command` (plus an optional `redirect_list`). The space is needed because `{` is a reserved word, not a special character.

Comment: Yes, rush's answer is correct, as I said. Yes, they are syntactically the same, as I said. But `brace_group`s behave differently when part of a function and when not. I was using *command grouping* to describe the latter case and this is what was described in rush's link.

Comment: I'm not sure the semantic distinction is significant here, as it is the syntax that matters to the parser.  The real answer is `{` is not an operator but a reserved word, and words need to be separated from other words in order to be considered distinct.